# Extraer datos de BodyExtractors.toMultipartData() Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring

Hola compañeros tengo una pregunta estoy recibiendo desde postman un id y un archivo excel utilizando BodyExtractors.toMultipartData(), obteniendo en consola pero el problema es extraerlos y llenarlo en mi getter.

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> updateCommissionChargeUseCase(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
return serverRequest.body(BodyExtractors.toMultipartData()).flatMap(x -> {
System.out.println("multipart");
    return ServerResponse.ok().bodyValue(x);

});
```

El constructor

```
public class RequestCommissionChargeDto {

private  int id;
private File file;
```

}

Router

```
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routerFunction(Handler handler) {
return route(POST("/chargecommission").and(RequestPredicates.accept(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)), handler::updateCommissionChargeUseCase);
}
```

estube tratando de hacerlo con Stream.of pero no se meda alguna idea como puedo llenar ese constructor?

salida de consola

[image: Consola]